# Clickable URL embedded in code

Tags: eclipse, plugins

Is there a plugin available for Eclipse that makes URL inside source code clickable? i.e. opens a browser window/tab to the URL.

E.g.

```
class SomeClass(object):
  """
  http://www.someurl.com/
  """
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holding down the CTRL whilst hovering over the URL pops a menu open.